# php array fusion line per line

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

i've two php array that i want to export on an excel.
i tried this:

```
 $tab=array_merge($tab1,$tab2);
 $activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
     ->fromArray(   $tab,   
                    NULL,       
                    'A1'  );
```

and i got this result

```
 BF     A   3,3032E+13
 BF-SA  A   3,0641E+13  
 220000000  165000  
 240000000  167334
```

It put tab2 data below tab1 data but i want it to put tab1 first line and tab2 fist line on the same line knowing that tab1 and tab2 have same number of line.

i've also tried $tab=$tab1+$tab2; but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Arrays have the same number of line as you said so you can use:

```
$tab1=[['BF', 'A' ,'3,3032E+13'],[ 'BF-SA' ,'A', '3,0641E+13']];  
$tab2=[[220000000,  165000]  , [240000000 , 167334 ]] ;

$tab=array_map(function($a,$b){return array_merge($a,$b);},$tab1,$tab2);
$activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
 ->fromArray(   $tab,   
                NULL,       
                'A1'  );
```